# Recommendation for Cloud native application for Alert notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

What is the recommendation for **Cloud native application** when it comes for Alert notification. I am aware that the log aggregators can be configured to look for specific **meta tags** to generate alerts but what if we want to generate alert from application in some complex business error.

Comment: "complex" is a relative term. Do you have any specific example of how "complex" the error is?

Comment: in case of one of many business rules fails. Then we need to send the alert to support for corrective action. Somthing similar to that